# Embedded infinispan - Initial state transfer timed out Error

Tags: infinispan

In the past few months I had an error during the Cache Manager initialization, resulting in my server being in an error state.

I use infinispan v13.0.13.Final in cluster mode with jgroups and 3 nodes that reboot each morning at different times: the first one @ 6:00, followed by the next one @ 6:05 and finally the last one.

Sometimes the first server (only the first) enters in a timeout status that throws an exeception. So, the cache manager and all my caches are never initializied.

Inifinispan prints the following log so at lest the method **org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded()** is executed correctly

```
Jan 11 06:00:32 hostname foo[3293956]: -------------------------------------------------------------------
Jan 11 06:00:32 hostname foo[3293956]: GMS: address=hostname-51836, cluster=cache-cluster-name, physical address=x.x.x.x:xxxx
Jan 11 06:00:32 hostname foo[3293956]: -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After ~4 minute (so before the next server reboots) I have this timeout error catched by my app. I guess that is generated by the method **org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete()** that is called by the start() method in the cacheImpl class

```
06:04:33.270 | ERROR (CacheServiceImpl.java:308) - Error init cache service
org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache org.infinispan.CONFIG on hostname-51836
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalStart(DefaultCacheManager.java:770) ~[infinispan-core-13.0.13.Final.jar:13.0.13.Final]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.start(DefaultCacheManager.java:734) ~[infinispan-core-13.0.13.Final.jar:13.0.13.Final]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:302) ~[infinispan-core-13.0.13.Final.jar:13.0.13.Final]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:224) ~[infinispan-core-13.0.13.Final.jar:13.0.13.Final]
```

Why that timeout occours and why the cache that throws this error is **org.infinispan.CONFIG**? i've never created such cache.

To fix this problem with a dirty solution i can disable the "wait for initial state" but i don't think it could be a good solution. Anyway i kindly ask you how can I programmatically disable this feature?

As an additional info, this error appears using infinispan v12 also and changing the reboot schedule a few hour before the other member.

Thanks in advance.